# html5lightbox video popup Mobile view Full screen issue

Tags: html, video, mobile, lightbox, html5-fullscreen

I am using HTML 5 light box popup for playing a video. i have been Calling video through web service from another website and stream into my player using html5-light-box popup using this method

```
html5Lightbox.showLightbox()
```

everything works fine but when viewed on mobile got to full screen video controls hide. when inspect element shown bottom of the video

Comment: that is normal behavior for most full-screen video... controls will disappear unless the user interacts with the screen (touch on mobile, mouse move on desktop etc)

Comment: when interact with screen  Still control does not appear . view this screen shot.. http://plrfox.com/img/video%20controls.png

Comment: what controls are you expecting? the full-screen player controls are there at the bottom (in full screen mode that's how the UI works)

Comment: it is at the bottom i want to display it on the video background on full screen  mode on mobile when touch to screen it appears user can pause or play or come out of full screen